# Segmentation Fault in overloading + operator

Tags: c++

I am writing a `class LongInt` and I have to overload `operator+`.

Currently, entering the values fine but when it goes into the function it shows a whole list of random numbers and then segmentation fault occurs (core dumped)

My function is :

```
LongInt LongInt::operator+(const LongInt num){
    LongInt sum;
    int k,j;
    //sum=number+num;
    if((size==num.size) || (size>num.size)){
        for(j=size;j>=2;j--){
            sum.number[j]=num.number[j]+number[j];
            if(sum.number[j]>10){
                k=sum.number[j]/10;
                sum.number[j]=sum.number[j]%10;
                number[j-1]+=number[j-1]+k;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        for(j=num.size;j>=2;j--){
            sum.number[j]=num.number[j]+number[j];
            if(sum.number[j]>10){
                k=sum.number[j]/10;
                sum.number[j]=sum.number[j]%10;
                number[j-1]+=number[j-1]+k;
            }
        }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: *Where* does it crash? Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: Have you tried your debugger?

Comment: And how does you class definition look like? More specifically, how is `number` declared and allocated?

Comment: Not the immediate problem, but you have a bad case of copy-paste coding - the two loops are virtually identical and could easily be re-factored into a single loop.

Answer (score 5):

The only suspecting thing is indexing of the arrays. (Wild guess)

You have set `j=num.size` and then you're using `num.number[j]` or `sum.number[j]` which can be the cause of fault.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are iterating over your arrays from `size` down to `1`.

Recall arrays run from `0` to `size-1`.

```
for(j=size;j>=2;j--)
```

Should be:

```
for(j=size-1;j>=1;j--)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using index that equal to size or num.size while the valid range as I understand is `[0, size - 1]`

Moreover if `size>num.size` then this statement

```
sum.number[j]=num.number[j]+number[j];
```

also invalid because num.number has no elements with indicies greater or equal than num.size.

Take into account that condition

```
if((size==num.size) || (size>num.size)){
```

can be written simpler

```
if( size >=num.size ){
```

And this condition

```
if(sum.number[j]>10){
```

is invalid. There must be

```
if(sum.number[j]>9){
```

Comment: thanks alot but this still doesn't solve the problem :/

Comment: @CS Student It solves the problem provided that you will do according to my remarks.

Comment: well yeah it somewhat did but the real problem was somewhere else thanks alot it really helped